# Как в классе обратиться к Объекту? В моем случаи к переменной number чтоб туда что-то вписать

Tags: c++, классы

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

class Phone_number {

public:
    int code, number;
    string type_number;
    Phone_number(const Phone_number& v) :
        code(v.code),
         number(v.number), 
          type_number(v.type_number){}
    const Phone_number& operator=(const Phone_number& v)
    {
        code = v.code;
        number = v.number;
        type_number = v.type_number;
        return v;
    }
};
int main() {
    
    
    int count = 0;
    cout << "Enter Telephone number" << endl;
    cin >> number ;

}
```

Comment: так-же как и к полю структуры

Comment: что бы обратится к "полю объекта" (переменной) нужно этот объект иметь. А у Вас его нет. Объявите переменную `Phone_number phone;` и теперь можно будет написать `cin >> phone.number'`

Comment: а как тут в коде можно использовать getline ? Просто если я ввожу номер к примеру: 380 111 111 111 то cin считывает до пробела а getline после.

Comment: вот кусочек кода int main() {
 int tel = 1;
 Phone_number* Phone1 = new Phone_number[tel];
 int count = 0;
 cout << "Enter Telephone number" << endl;
 for (int i = 0; i < tel; i++) {
  cin >> Phone1[i].number;
 }
 for (int i = 0; i < tel; i++) {
  cout << Phone1[i].number<<endl;
 }

}